# How to iterate simultaneously over two lists using thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am new to thymeleaf and In my current spring-boot project, I have this thymeleaf code:

```
<table class="table table-hover" id="table">
          <thead  style="background-color:#CCE5FF">
            <tr>  
                <th>ID</th>                     
                <th>Code</th>                   
                <th>Created Date</th>
                <th>EMP Account</th>
                <th>Bank Name</th>
                <th></th> 
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr th:each="emp,iterStat : ${empList}">//accList-another list
                <td th:text="${emp.id}">ID</td>
                <td th:text="${emp.mdrcode}">Code</td>
                <td th:text="${emp.createDate}">Created Date</td> 
                <td th:text="${}">Emp Account</td>
                <td th:text="${}">Bank Name</td>                     
                <td><a  id="editview" class="btn btn-sm btn-default" th:href="@{/}"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> View</a></td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
            </tbody>
          </table>
```

Here i have details in two lists,one list values getting successfully.
But i don't know how to get second list values.

I am trying to iterate two list at a time in `th:each` but i didn't get the values.

Comment: Did you solve that?

Answer (score 4):

Iterate over first list and get value from second list by index.

```
<tr th:each="emp,iterStat : ${empList}">
    <td th:text="${emp.id}">ID</td>
    <td th:text="${accList[iterStat.index].field}">Emp Account</td> 
</tr>.
```

Comment: @Durga Arrays of the same length?

Answer (score 0):

If lists have the same size:

```
<tr th:each="emp,iterStat : ${empList}">
    <td th:text="${emp.id}">ID</td>
    <td th:text="${accList[__${iterStat.index}__].field}">Emp Account</td> 
</tr>
```